# how to rule:send email after email moved to folder?

Tags: automation, mail-rule

I would like to create a rule that does the following.

1. Email comes in
2. After I move the read email into a folder/subfolder, it triggers a rule to send an email to a specific user that this email was moved into a specific folder.

TIA

Comment: See if the following applies:   Create a new Rule. Step I, select the first condition (what email). Step 2:  Here you can both Put it in a Folder AND also Reply or Forward at the same time.  I think this might satisfy your objective.